# Are there any alternatives to COM+ transaction based data-access layer?

Tags: asp.net

We are using our data-access layer with COM+. It's suboptimal. But the reasons to keep it are that it's transaction-secure. Are there any other alternatives to transcation-secure data-access handling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TransactionScope and System.Transactions have been around since 2005

Answer (score 1):

What kind of data access? To relational databases? Simple ADO.Net as well as Entity Framework supports transactions.